# Need php code to store file uploaded with wget

Tags: php, bash, http, post, wget

I need to upload file on server from command line. I do next:

```bash
wget -d --post-file=links.txt http://bearnova.com/upload_file.php
```

Here is upload_file.php . Code below doesn't work of course:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

}
?>
```

Wget does an HTTP POST to send file.
I've also heard about $_POST, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and file_get_contents(php://input)
I'm not a php guy at all. So could someone please help me to get a valid solution?
Thanks.

Comment: wget command you write is not send a file to server. It sends post request with data located in links.txt file

Comment: What about $_POST, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA? Can I read file contents from one of it?

Comment: link you send below(http://www.noah.org/wiki/WGET_CGI_Post) explains how you send file with wget very well. Which point you can't get it?

Comment: I dont get why we need to do base64.encodestring and then decode it. Also I don't need a python part at all.

Comment: Because you need convert file content to a string so that wget can send it as post variable. You can also do it with bash if you dont want to use python. I am writing a answer now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get contents of file this way:

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA - the same as the above but depends on php.ini (empty in my case)

I need to store it in file on server side and it seems that filename was not sent either but it should be not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` can't be used for file uploads. File uploads require that the content type be `multipart/form-data`, but `wget` doesn't support this. From the man page:

> Wget does not currently support `multipart/form-data' for transmitting POST data; only`
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

`--post-file` just posts ordinary form fields, it just gets the values from the contents of the file.

You can do what you want with `curl` instead.

```bash
curl -F file=@links.txt http://bearnova.com/upload_file.php
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't have a curl. I need to do it exactly with wget.

Comment: It says right there in the documentation that wget can't send file attachments. Why can't you install curl?

Comment: Again. I'm on OM2P access point which has only wget and scp. There is no curl, ftp, sftp, tftp, wput etc. And I need to send logs from shell script.

Comment: Then I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: This problem was already solved once but I was not on the server-side and I don't know the solution. So I believe this could be done.
Here is one of examples: http://www.noah.org/wiki/WGET_CGI_Post

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it with wget.

```
wget -d --post-data="filedata=`base64 links.txt`&filename=links.txt" http://bearnova.com/upload_file.php
```

you can get filename and filedata from upload_file.php, and do whatever you want.

```
<?php
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    $filedata = base64_decode($_POST['filedata']);
?>
```

Comment: yeah, that works fine except I dont have base64 on AP ;)

Answer (score -1):

Please check, In the html form you defined enctype or not

```
<form method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
</form>
```

If its not defined then also it might be not working.
As, for file field this enctype in form is needed.

Comment: he doesn't have an HTML form. He's using `wget` to do the form submission.

Comment: as Barmar said I dont have a form ;)